# Expected String, got nil

Tags: string, lua, numbers, null

I have the following code which should just print a number, but instead it prints the mentioned error:

```
print(
  math.abs(
    tonumber(TColor, 16) -
    tonumber(FColor, 16)
  ) / 100 * (math.abs(minV - maxV) / 100 * curV) + tonumber(FColor, 16)
)
```

even `tostring( math...... )` couldn't solve it

Comment: And the values for `TColor`, `FColor`, `minV` and `maxV`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because one of the `Tcolor` or `Fcolor` is `nil`. The error is being thrown by `tonumber()`.

You can see it being reproduced [here](http://codepad.org/gpavOTi6).